How to prove : If $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ is strictly increasing then $\lim_{x\to b}f(x)\neq-\infty$
How can we prove the statement: if $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ is strictly increasing then $\lim_{x\to b}f(x)\neq-\infty$
I think I was able to prove this adding an extra restriction that $f$ is continuous, as shown bellow.
Assume for contradiction that $\lim_{x\to b}f(x)=-\infty$
The codomain of $f$ is $$f((a,b))=(\lim_{x\to a}f(x),\lim_{x\to b}f(x))=(\lim_{x\to a}f(x), -\infty)$$
Case 1: $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=+\infty$ then $$\exists y_1,y_2 \text{in the neighborhood of $a$ and $b$ respectively with }y_1<y_2 \text{  s.t  }\\f(y_1)>f(y_2)$$ Which is a contradiction to $f$ being strictly increasing on the interval $(a,b)$
Case 2: $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=l\in\mathbb{R}$ then:
$$\exists y_3 \text{ in the neighborhood of $a$ s.t } f(y_3)>f(y_2)$$ Which is a contradiction to $f$ being strictly increasing.
Case 3: $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=-\infty$ then
$$f((a,b))=(-\infty,-\infty)=\{-\infty\}$$
Which is a contradiction to $f$ being a real function.
So there cannot exist a continuous strictly increasing function $f$ defined on $(a,b)$ such that $\lim_{x\to b}f(x)=-\infty$. Q.E.D.
If the restriction that $f$ is continuous is removed how could one prove/disprove the statement?

$(x,-\infty)$ is always an empty set. Your interval-based reasoning is a little vague. If you write out the actual definition of $\lim_{x \to b} f(x) = -\infty$, the proof should be obvious.

Should the limit be as $x\to b^-$?

Choose any $c\in (a,b)$. For all $x\in (c,b)$ we have $f(x)>f(c)$ by assumption. This alone proves that $f$ cannot tend to $-\infty$ as $x\to b^-$. You don't need continuity.

$-\infty + a=-\infty$ where $a$ is a positive number. Is my reasoning invalid here? What I mean is Obviously for a function to tend to $-\infty$ and be increasing at the same time , has to give really really small numbers for every value of $x$. Can you point me in the right direction? Thanks for your answer and thank you in advance.

I don't understand your question. As I showed, the values here will not be "too small", they will be at least $f(c)$.

Suppose $f(x)\to -\infty$ as $ x\to b$. Consider the point $c=\frac{a+b}{2}$. By definition of convergence to $-\infty$ there is a $\delta>0$ that $b-\delta < x < b$ implies $f(c) > f(x)$. Since we can chose such an $x$ greater than $c$ this shows $f$ cannot be increasing.
